# Hive date is displayed as NULL when table is queried

Tags: date, timestamp, hive

I have a table in Hive which has field with Date datatype. Table is an external table and the date values are is as follows in the text file `"04/14/2006 00:00:00"`, When I query the table I get NULL for this field. Can someone help me to get the date as it is like that in text file.

Answer (score 0):

**Timestamps**

Supports traditional UNIX timestamp with optional nanosecond precision.
Integer numeric types: Interpreted as UNIX timestamp in seconds
Floating point numeric types: Interpreted as UNIX timestamp in seconds with decimal precision
Strings: JDBC compliant java.sql.Timestamp format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.fffffffff" (9 decimal place precision)

Timestamps are interpreted to be timezoneless and stored as an offset from the UNIX epoch. Convenience UDFs for conversion to and from timezones are provided (to_utc_timestamp, from_utc_timestamp).

All existing datetime UDFs (month, day, year, hour, etc.) work with the TIMESTAMP data type.
Timestamps in text files have to use the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.f...]. If they are in another format declare them as the appropriate type (INT, FLOAT, STRING, etc.) and use a UDF to convert them to timestamps.

**Dates**

DATE values describe a particular year/month/day, in the form YYYY-­MM-­DD. For
example, DATE '2013-­01-­01'. Date types do not have a time of day component.
The range of values supported for the Date type is be 0000-­01-­01 to 9999-­12-­31, dependent on
support by the primitive Java Date type.

[Source](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-timestamp)

So If You need to print the Date as it is then Will suggest to Use String Data Type instead of DateTime Data type.

Answer (score -1):

If you have time data in the format other than **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS** & if you set **timestamp** as the **datatype** in HIVE Table, then hive will display NULL when queried.

You can use a simple trick here, Open your .csv data file in Microsoft Excel. Select the entire column, **rightclick>Format Cells>Custom>type** in the text box the required format (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) and press OK/Apply. Your data will then be displayed in the Hive acceptable format of timestamp and will be loaded appropriately in HIVE. You can check it by querying HIVE.Cheers :)